# File upload window after Sweet Alert

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sweetalert

**Use Case:**

- I'm trying to change **`window.alert` to Sweet alert**.
- When I used **`window.alert`**, alert pop-up appeared before file-upload window and then clicked 'OK', file upload window appeared.
- But, after changing `window.alert` to Sweet alert, file-upload window appears simultaneously.

  `<label for="ScanFile"><i class="fa fa-upload" style='cursor: pointer;' ng-click="uploadAlert(row)"></i></label>
  <input id="ScanFile" type="file"/>`

When a user clicks the label, Sweet-alert appeared, and then the user can select the file.

**uploadAlert() :**

```
$scope.uploadAlert = function() {
        $window.alert(~~~~~~);
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: is `<input id="ScanFile" type="file"/>` show to the user in the UI?

Comment: yes, that is User's view

Comment: i meant is the label that is shown to the user or Choosefile button, or both are visible ?

Comment: just label shown. I hide file input using CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <label for="ScanFile"><i class="fa fa-upload" style='cursor: pointer;' ng-click="uploadAlert(event, row)"></i></label>
 <input id="ScanFile" type="file"/>
```

your uploadAlert() function will be like,

```
$scope.uploadAlert = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the upload dialog from opening
    swal(); // sweetalert popup
}
```

now you can programatically click on the `<input id="ScanFile" type="file"/>` using the id, to open the dialog after closing sweetalert dialog.

```
 document.getElementById("ScanFile").click();
```

For example:

```
 $scope.uploadAlert = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the upload dialog from opening
       swal({
      title: 'Demo',
      text: 'Demo',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
      },
      function() {
         document.getElementById("ScanFile").click();
     });
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I should use `$event` than `event` in `ng-click`